# ExecutorService not properly calling interrupt()

Tags: java, sockets, executorservice

I created an ExecutorService to manage all of my separate threads that are each handling a socket connection. I overrode the interrupt method in each of those threads to close the socket when the thread is interrupted in case the socket is currently in a uninterruptable method (like socketserver.accept()).

If I manually call the interrupt on my threads when the application is closing, everything shuts down properly. However, if I use my ExecutorService and run shutdownNow, it doesn't seem to be calling the overridden interrupt method at all.

Why isn't it calling my overridden method?

Comment: how are you getting your Threads into the ExecutorService?  are you using a custom ThreadFactory?

Comment: I figured out the problem. ExecutorService wraps the Runnable it takes as an argument, so that's why passing in a Thread didn't do anything. What's strange is that making a custom Thread created by a custom ThreadFactory with a special close method that is called when interrupt is called and passing this ThreadFactory to ExecutorService still did not work, but I ultimately scrapped it and made a special queue of my Runnables with uninterruptable methods which clears them separately of ExecutorService instead of probing further.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a solution using the thread pool.  See below for a description and simplified code.

1) Created my own thread class which overrides interrupt() to also call a close() method which is configured using a set method and Closeable interface that I created.  Override interrupt() to call the close method if configured.

```
public class CloseableThread extends Thread {
    private Closeable mCloseable = null;

    public interface Closeable {
        void close();
    }

    // Constructors deleted

    public void interrupt() {
        super.interrupt();
        if (mCloseable != null) {
            mCloseable.close();
        }
    }

    public void setCloseable(Closeable closeable) {
        mCloseable = closeable;
    }
}
```

2) Created my own pool class which extends ThreadPool that has a factory for my closeable thread and overrides beforeExecute() to set the closeable.

```
public class CloseableThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
    static class CloseableThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            return (Thread) new CloseableThread(r);
        }
    }

    // Constructors deleted

    @Override
    protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
        super.beforeExecute(t, r);

        if (t instanceof CloseableThread && r instanceof Closeable) {
            ((CloseableThread) t).setCloseable((Closeable) r);
        }
    }
}
```

3)  Make sure that any task that uses sockets implements Closeable and the close() method somehow causes the socket to close.  Make sure to cleanly handle the socket exception that will be generated when closing this way.